# bind (hardlink) one directory to many places

Tags: mount, ext4

I need to "bind" one directory to many chrooted places. I know that I can do "mount -o bind", but this requires special processing on startup each time (run the mount).

Is there a way to do it on filesystem directly? My fs is ext4 and it seems not to support hardlinks to directories. Hardlinking all files inside is not an option too.

Is thee a way to enable hardlinks to directories in ext4?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add your mount details to `/etc/fstab`. Since you didn't give much details, I can only point you to the manual page: `man fstab`.

Comment: I've one folder to point to 2000 places (each in it's own chrooted place). It's not an option to have 2000 fstab records!